# A realtime priority application is consuming all of CPU

Tags: ram, pop-os, dmesg, cpu-usage, real-time

I am running **PopOs 22.04** on my **dell laptop [amd64, intel i3, 4GB ram]**. The booting was taking so much time, so I run `sudo dmesg` in terminal and it shows error:

```
rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt detected expedited stalls on CPUs/tasks: { P1844 } 6 jiffies s: 417 root: 0x0/T
```

after searching, it means a realtime priority process is consuming all CPU space, so I run htop.

It shows that `io.elementary.appcenter` is consuming **54 % of cpu and 700mb of ram**. also `firefox` consumes high ram uses about **25 % of ram**.

I tried some methods to get rid of `io.elementary.appcenter` but didn't succeed. I don't know what to do. If anyone know the solution, please help..

Comment: Firefox: that's quite normal. You don't realize it, but websites these days are actually complex pieces of software that run on your machine. Most of them are written as if electricity was free and everyone has a modern MacBook with 32 GB of RAM just to run the website.

Comment: This issue has been going on for a while now. (More than 2 years).
See this [issue](https://github.com/pop-os/shop/issues/257).
From the discussion, PoP OS developers were not so happy about how people complained about this. And they promised that a fix was on the way.
Fast forward to 2023, and it is still present in Pop OS 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

This issue *"a realtime priority has consuming all of CPU"* was with the previous ISO file of Pop OS 22.04. The Pop OS team has solved the problem and this issue has gone in the newer ISO file of Pop OS 22.04